# Terminal Error : lmer() model- Error in valid(.Object)

Tags: command-line, r, putty

I am trying to run a lmer() model on R (terminal supercomputer) the job is kind of big so I cannot run it time efficiently on my personal RStudio. I am running an test model: lmer(Yr_IT_RATE ~ Entry + Rep + (1|Block) , data = DatRust

I get this error:

> Error in validObject(.Object) :
>     invalid class “corMatrix” object: 'sd' slot has non-finite entries
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In vcov.merMod(model) :
>     Computed variance-covariance matrix problem: not a positive definite matrix;
>   returning NA matrix

### I ran a command of validObject(fit1) the result was TRUE

I ran this same model on my RStudio and I never got this error. I am to get an ANOVA and emmeans from this model on my personal RStudio.

I don't know what is going or how to make this work on terminal.

Ultimately, the model I want to try to run is:

> fit2.1 <- lmer(Yr_IT_RATE ~ ENTRY*LOCATION + (LOCATION|REP:BLOCK), data = RUST_DAT)
>
> fit2.2 <- lmer(Yr_Sev_PCNT ~ ENTRY*LOCATION + (LOCATION|REP) + (LOCATION|REP:BLOCK), data = RUST_DAT)

I am not able to find any information on the web.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks!